# STM32duino clock configuration for NUCLEO-F446RE

Tags: arduino, stm32

I bought the
STM32F446RE, mbed-Enabled Development Nucleo STM32F4 MCU 32-Bit ARM® Cortex®-M4 Embedded Evaluation Board

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/stmicroelectronics/NUCLEO-F446RE/497-15882-ND/5347712

I noticed this; STM32duino (workshop to get started with STM32 and Arduino software ecosystem)

https://youtu.be/FzxLPDNBqng

and I'm trying this on my 64-bit Windows 10 laptop + ARDUINO IDE 1.8.9.

The NUCLEO-F446RE can run up to 180MHz (CPU clock frequency). When I use the default settings from STM32duino, I think I have to do some configuration in order to run on 180 MHz.

For instance, I inserted a LED toggling code in the loop to see how fast can this iterate. I used my oscilloscope and it took microseconds to finish the loop, a loop which only has a toggling feature.

When you buy the NUCLEO-F446RE, only the 32kHz crystal is populated. High frequency (ex. 8MHz) oscillators are not installed.

**Is there a way to make my NUCLEO-F446RE run at 180MHz when using the ARDUINO IDE & STM32duino?**

I think the code will change if I install an 8MHz crystal or use the internal oscillator.

*Or, I'm using the STM32CubeMx 5, if there is a way to migrate the STM32CubeMx to STM32duino, that can work (although I haven't found this way on Google).*

**Thanks for your help.**

Comment: I afraid you need to learn a bit about the programming and microcontrollers. Normally I would advice to take a close look at the clock init function. But I afraid it will not work this time

Comment: `enableClock ` you mean [this](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32/blob/master/cores/arduino/stm32/clock.c)? My problem is that I couldn't find an example that uses this and that's why I'm asking, please.

Comment: you have sourced right at the front of your eyes. if can't even find the file it is too early for you to amend it